# Run XMonad's startup hook only on initial startup

Tags: startup, xmonad

I have the following `startupHook` in my `xmonad.hs`

```
, startupHook = spawn "~/.xmonad/autostart"
```

I am starting many apps and daemons in this script and it is written to run *only* once on startup. But this is being run everytime I hit `Mod-q`, i.e., to reload and test out my changes to `xmonad.hs`.

I could conditionally run the programs in the autostart script but that turned out to be quite flaky. So, I was wondering if there is a way to xmonad to run this startup hook only on the initial startup and not on reloads.

I tried googling around but came up empty. Is such a thing possible?

Edit: I am running xmonad 0.11 installed from cabal on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentionned in the [FAQ](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#Startup_programs), the `startupHook` is run each time xmonad is restarted with <kbd>MOD</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Also from a software point of view, it seems important that a *restart* is not different than a *stop* followed by a *start*. Thus there is no way to differentiate a *start* from a *restart* from within Xmonad. Hence each time Xmonad is started, it will launch the `startupHook`

To run programs on startup, they propose to use the usual manner by adding them to `.xsession` or `.Xinitrc`.

In your case you can just put

```
~/.xmonad/autostart
```

at the end of your `.Xinitrc` file.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think the `.Xinitrc` file is run by LightDM, that is used by Ubuntu. Currently I have a line saying `test -n "$(pgrep nm-applet)" && exit 0`, so that if `nm-applet` is already running, I assume its a restart. Not a solution I'm proud of, but it works. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: The problem with this is that I can't use "spawnOn" in .xsession! Maybe there is something I can check in the startupHook, indicating initial start or restart?

Comment: Is there a difference between putting something on the `startupHook` and putting directly in the `main` function?

Answer (score 7):

One very slightly dodgy workaround if you're using Ubuntu, and possibly other Debian-based systems, and have installed XMonad via your package manager (which doesn't actually help the person who asked the initial question, but might help others):

Add whatever programs you want to launch to `~/.xmonad/xmonad-session-rc`, as if it were a bash script (you don't need to make it executable).

### Explanation

In Ubuntu, XMonad is launched from the login screen thanks to `/usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop`. The program executed by this is  not `xmonad` itself, but the bash script `xmonad-session` (present at `/usr/bin/xmonad`), which sources `.xmonad/xmonad-session-rc` and hence the contents of that file will be executed when you first log in to xmonad.

The workaround is slightly dodgy, as I think that the purpose of the `xmonad-session-rc` file was to set environment variables, not run programs, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2):

If you use xmonad-contrib, simply `import Xmonad.Util.SpawnOnce` and then use `spawnOnce` instead of `spawn` in your startup hook.